# Android: Screen orientation reporting too slow?

Tags: android, canvas, screen-rotation

I am using the `Display.getRotation()` method to determine the current orientation of the screen in my App, per this helpful blog entry from Google:

http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2010/09/one-screen-turn-deserves-another.html

In a nutshell, I have a drawing app that allows the user to draw shapes, etc to the screen, and the drawing canvas needs to stay in the same orientation, but I still wanted to the Options menu, etc to flip to the correct location if and when the user starts drawing with the device in a different orientation.

In `onDraw()` for the canvas, I request the orientation from `getRotation()` and then rotate the canvas back to the '0' location so that from the end-user's perspective, the canvas never moves.  Works like a charm *EXCEPT* if the user flips the device *VERY* quickly... then `getRotation()` reports a rotation of 0, and thus the canvas doesn't rotate back, making the drawing appear flipped or turned.

Interestingly, the title bar and options menus do flip... so not sure where they are getting the orientation from. If the user then starts to draw, the subsequent call to `onDraw()` gets the correct rotation vale and the drawing goes back to the correct location, but it is a bit unnerving/annoying as you can imagine.  Any strategies on dealing with this?

Thanks.

Comment: I would love to see the answer to this one. I'm experiencing a similar issue on my app.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using getOrientation() instead... I'm not sure where your issue stems from but who knows, it could give you a different result.

```
Display myDisplay = ((WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE)).getDefaultDisplay();         
int rotation = myDisplay.getOrientation();
switch (rotation) {
    case Surface.ROTATION_0: { doSomething(); break; }
    case Surface.ROTATION_90: { doSomething(); break; }                 
    case Surface.ROTATION_270: { doSomething(); break; }                    
    case Surface.ROTATION_180: { doSomething(); break; }
}
```

Comment: Bad idea. `getOrientation` has been deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

Use onOrientationChanged().  It returns the current angle in degrees.  It seems to work reliably for display orientation changes.  I convert the angle into the 4 standard orientations like this:

```
    myOrientationEventListener = new OrientationEventListener(this, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL)
    {

        @Override
        public void onOrientationChanged(int iAngle)
        {                         // 0  15 30 45 60 75, 90 105, 120, 135, 150, 165, 180, 195, 210, 225, 240, 255, 270, 285, 300, 315, 330, 345
            final int iLookup[] = {0,   0, 0,90,90, 90,90, 90,  90, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 180, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 270, 0, 0, 0}; // 15-degree increments 
            if (iAngle != ORIENTATION_UNKNOWN)
            {
                int iNewOrientation = iLookup[iAngle / 15];
                if (iOrientation != iNewOrientation)
                {
                iOrientation = iNewOrientation;
                <do something with new orientation>
                }  
            }
        }
    };
```